# TableView custom cell

Tags: iphone

how can I use custom cell in table view? Please give me suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a video tutorial, enjoy:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/05/24/custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder/

http://eu-video-cloud.s3.amazonaws.com/available/114103480/asset-61/encoded_hidef.mp4